# $\mathbb{P}\{\lim_{n \to \infty }|Z_n - Z| = 0\} = 1 \iff \mathbb{P}\{\limsup_{n \to \infty} |Z_n - Z| = 0\} = 1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In a proof I read, it is claimed that for a sequence $(Z_n)_n$ of random variables:

$\mathbb{P}\{\lim_{n \to \infty} |Z_n - Z| = 0\} = 1 \iff \mathbb{P}\{\limsup_{n \to \infty} |Z_n - Z| = 0\} = 1$

I can see that $\implies$ holds, but why does the other implication hold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\limsup_{n\to\infty}|Z_n-Z|=0$ then
$$
0\le|Z_n-Z|\le\sup_{k\ge n}|Z_k-Z|\to 0,\quad n\to\infty.
$$
What can you conclude about the limit?

Answer (score 2):

If $(a_n)_n$ is a sequence of nonnegative elements of $\mathbb R$ then:$$\limsup a_n=0\implies \lim a_n=0$$This because$$0\leq a_n\leq\sup_{k\geq n}a_k$$for every $n$.

Comment: I prefer this answer, as it elucidates the point that the equivalence does not require any probabilistic argument. (+1)